# Escaping & when passed as a parameter for URLs with Spring's UriComponentBuilder (for REST API GET call)

Tags: java, spring, rest, url, uri

I am trying to build a URL for a GET REST API call. In the URL I have two ways in which ampersand sign is being used. At one place, & is used to separate the parameters, and at the second place it the part of the parameter.

for example, if param is "gummy bear", the url is:

```
https://sandbox.localhost.com/rest?sysparm_fields=sys_id&param=gummy bear
```

and the encoded url is:

```
https://sandbox.localhost.com/rest?sysparm_fields=sys_id&param=gummy%20bear
```

But is the param is "M&M^sys=good"

```
No Encoding :: https://sandbox.localhost.com/rest?sysparm_fields=sys_id&param=M&M^sys=good
Encoded URI :: https://sandbox.localhost.com/rest?sysparm_fields=sys_id&param=M&M%5Esys=good
```

Here is the code for it, the issue is in the getIdbyGroup() method and I have got a working version in the getIdbyGroupManualFix() method:

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;

public class Execute {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        getIdbyGroup("gummy bear");
        getIdbyGroup("M&M^sys=good");

        getIdbyGroupManualFix("M&M^sys=good");
    }

    public static void getIdbyGroup(String parameter) {
        System.out.println("Issue Method ::");
        System.out.println("parameter :: " + parameter);
        String baseUrl = "https://sandbox.localhost.com/rest";

        UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(baseUrl);
        builder.queryParam("sysparm_fields", "sys_id");
        builder.query("param=" + parameter);

        System.out.println("No Encoding :: " + builder.build().toString());

        URI uri = builder.build().encode().toUri();
        System.out.println("Encoded URI :: " + uri.toString());

    }

    public static void getIdbyGroupManualFix(String parameter) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Fix ::");
        System.out.println("parameter :: " + parameter);
        String baseUrl = "https://sandbox.localhost.com/rest";

        UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(baseUrl);
        builder.queryParam("sysparm_fields", "sys_id");

        //encoding the parameter
        String encodedValue = URLEncoder.encode(parameter, "UTF-8");

        builder.query("param=" + encodedValue);

        System.out.println("Partially Encoded :: " + builder.build().toString());

        URI uri = new URI(builder.build().toString());
        System.out.println("Double Encoded URI :: " + uri.toString());

    }
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
Issue Method ::
parameter :: gummy bear
No Encoding :: https://sandbox.localhost.com/rest?sysparm_fields=sys_id&param=gummy bear
Encoded URI :: https://sandbox.localhost.com/rest?sysparm_fields=sys_id&param=gummy%20bear
Issue Method ::
parameter :: M&M^sys=good
No Encoding :: https://sandbox.localhost.com/rest?sysparm_fields=sys_id&param=M&M^sys=good
Encoded URI :: https://sandbox.localhost.com/rest?sysparm_fields=sys_id&param=M&M%5Esys=good
Fix ::
parameter :: M&M^sys=good
Partially Encoded :: https://sandbox.localhost.com/rest?sysparm_fields=sys_id&param=M%26M%5Esys%3Dgood
Double Encoded URI :: https://sandbox.localhost.com/rest?sysparm_fields=sys_id&param=M%26M%5Esys%3Dgood
```

Is there a better way of encoding the & sign in the parameter?

Comment: Have you tried to pass &amp;?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it.

Comment: Two ideas: 1) Pass a small object, maybe JSON encoded in the body of the POST.  2) base64 encode the param name and base64 decode it on the receiving end.

Comment: I do not have control over the receiving end. It is a third party API.